# How to automate connecting to OpenVPN with MFA?

Tags: openvpn, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to connect to OpenVPN via the command

```
sudo /usr/local/opt/openvpn/sbin/openvpn --config ~/.ssh/client.ovpn --auth-user-pass ~/.ssh/credentials_vpn
```

If there is no MFA enabled, this command works fine, but when MFA is enabled, it asks for MFA as in screenshot

[image: mfa]

I wish to automate this process. I have already found the totp solution. I'm using totp for the same. I can generate the totp using

```
totp vpn
```

[image: totp]

But I am not able to automate the process of entering this into the vpn connect command. I have tried to find available options of openvpn cli, there is none which helped. I even tried

```
--static-challenge $(totp vpn) 1
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The otp appears, but I still have to enter it. see ss
[image]

Any response is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem and I didn't solve it yet... I tried even using pseudo-terminals to try to mimic the typing, but it's still a pain to do that, all that stuff is complicated as it is because it's an interface with the PAM module... because we could just pipe the top result to OpenVPN initialization. In that case, I'm almost using xdotool to be used as background task... with is terrible for n reasons

Comment: I also have this same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it is doable with xdotools, your script would look like this (you can also use the "pass" utility instead of storing credentials in plain text files):

```
#!/bin/bash

VPNotp="$(totp vpn)"

# uncommant the following 2 lines to use "pass" password manager instead of plain text files
### VPNpass="$(pass vpn_pass)"
### VPNotp="$(pass otp OTP_of_your user)"

xdotool type "sudo /usr/local/opt/openvpn/sbin/openvpn --config ~/.ssh/client.ovpn --auth-user-pass ~/.ssh/credentials_vpn"
xdotool key Return
xdotool type "$VPNpass$VPNotp"
xdotool key Return
unset VPNpass VPNotp
```

The main issue is the sudo, as you do the sudo execution, the output of the command which was executed by the previous user, won't be handled anymore. In this case the `$(totp vpn)` command is executed first in a sub-shell, with your iarc13 user.
I faced the same issue, and it seems almost impossible to pass the output to the CLI after switching user.
If you don't have `xdotools`, a possible workaround could be to copy the output to the clipboard and paste it back. It is not as convenient as passing it within the CLI, but at least it is working.
If you have xclip installed the command would be:
`totp vpn | xclip -selection clipboard; sudo /usr/local/opt/openvpn/sbin/openvpn --config ~/.ssh/client.ovpn --auth-user-pass ~/.ssh/credentials_vpn`
And than you can simply paste the OTP code to the CLI.

Comment: Thanks @jpeter01, for your attempt. And about that copy to clipboard - The totp tool automatically copies it to clipboard :)

Comment: Could the `yes` command be used here?